# How to change the normal flow of Inline CSS elements from left to right?

Tags: css

I have inline CSS elements and I want to change the normal flow from left-right to right-left.
How to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a 
`div
{
direction:rtl;
}`

This will work for `div style="display:inline"` and for `<td>`s.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work well for `<span>` and some other elements.

Comment: I tried this,but it is used only with text,right?I have "ul" inline elements.Thanks

Comment: My inline elements are <span> .Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Then what you need might be the `float: right;` attribute. Try this one.

Comment: I also tried this but didn't help.Actually the inline elements are primary menu links.So I want the last element of the second line to go to the left instead of the right of the line.

Comment: Sure,in this site  http://dev.amnesty.io1developer.com/  under primary links I want to move the AI@50 link from left to right(under SCHOOLS).How to do that?Thanks

Comment: If you apply `float:right` to your `li` elements, it sort of does what you want, however, also the buttons in the top bar are in reversed order.

Comment: Isn't [this (link)](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9448/screenshot1ti.png) what you wanted to achieve? The only thing I changed was adding `float:right` to `#primary li`

Comment: Ok,the "float:right: " helped me move the link to the right,but it also moved and the other menus.How to ONLY move the one menu to the right?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your HTML elements.

CSS is for presentation, not for structure.